# Verify OTP for shipping mobile number in checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, mobile

I need to verify the OTP for the mobile number(in the shipping address) on the checkout page. How can I programmatically achieve?. Please, can u guide me which module to be overridden to achieve the functionality?